# Check if a word is between two other words, by alphabetical order

Tags: python, string, alphabetical

I want to check if a given word is between two other words, by alphabetical (or "dictionary") order.

For example:

```
word1 = 'feelgoodlab'
word2 = 'elainedilley'
check = 'feelingfat'
```

I want to see if `check` is between `word1` and `word2` (it is).

I tried this:

```
word1 = 'feelgoodlab'
word2 = 'elainedilley'
check = 'feelingfat'

print(check >= word1 and check <= word2)
```

but that's giving me `False`.

Comment: Well it is the opposite here: `check >= word2 and check <= word1`.

Comment: Your statement that check is between word1 and word2 is incorrect, at-least from how string comparison works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you here basically check if:

```
word1 <= check <= word2
```

But here, it is the opposite: `word2` is less, and `word1` is greater, we can however compbine the two possibilities with:

```
word1 <= check <= word2 or word2 <= check <= word1
```

So here regardless of what the order is between `word1` and `word2`, it checks if `check` is "*sandwiched*" in between.

Comment: To add, this method is called *chained comparisons* and is detailed in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).